# Selecting key/value in nested JSON with key which is number stored as string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have nested JSON file which I can access like this:

```
jsonObject['results']['query']['1']
```

I would like to iterate over `jsonObject['results']['query']` but when I create loop like this:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    pageNo = '\''+str(i)+'\''
    print(pageNo)
    print(jsonObject['results']['query'][pageNo])
```

it gives me error:

> KeyError: " '1' "

While line `print(pageNo)` prints `'1'` which works fine when I use it in:

```
 jsonObject['results']['query']['1']
```

What's the catch?

Comment: Why are you using this `'\''+str(i)+'\''`. What did you get when you used `str(i)` only?

Comment: You're embedding literal single-quotes in the string.  Don't do that.

Comment: what you are trying to access is `jsonObject['results']['query']['\'1\'']` , there is no key `'\'1\''`

Comment: @Alok that worked..I was sure I tried that already and that it didn't work...silly me.